# Mule Mongo Connector to produce INNER JOIN results

Tags: mongodb, join, mule

I have two collections, one of organizations and one of brands within the organization, and I am trying to produce a result set that will have the brands related to the organization show up as as a nested JSON inside the organization JSON result.

The code for getting the results looks like this, and it does return the expected results, however the final JSON has quotes in it for each brad. How can I include the brands' JSON without including it as a string?

Query a single org by Mongo ID from Mongo:

```
    <mongo:find-one-object-using-query-map config-ref="mdb_config" collection="orgs" doc:name="Fetch object from Mongo">
        <mongo:query-attributes>                
            <mongo:query-attribute key="_id">#[new org.bson.types.ObjectId(flowVars.OrgId)]</mongo:query-attribute>
        </mongo:query-attributes>
    </mongo:find-one-object-using-query-map>
    <mongo:db-object-to-map doc:name="Map Mongo object to hashmap"/>
```

Query for the orgs Brands List:

```
    <foreach collection="#[payload.brands]" doc:name="For Each" rootMessageVariableName="rootMessage">
        <mongo:find-one-object-using-query-map config-ref="mdb_config" collection="brands" doc:name="Fetch brands for org">
            <mongo:query-attributes>                
                <mongo:query-attribute key="_id">#[new org.bson.types.ObjectId(message.payload)]</mongo:query-attribute>
            </mongo:query-attributes>
        </mongo:find-one-object-using-query-map >

        <!-- Transform the brand from Mongo to JSON schema compliant JSON -->
            <scripting:transformer doc:name="Map Mongo object to JSON">
                <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
                     def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
                     def root = builder {
                         brandId payload._id.toString()
                         //...
                         isActive payload.platformHeader.isActive
                     }
                     return builder.toPrettyString();
                 ]]></scripting:script>
            </scripting:transformer>
        <expression-component>brandResponses.add(message.payloadAs(java.lang.String))
        </expression-component>
        <logger message="The result is #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </foreach> 
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[brandResponses]"/>
            <!-- Transform the org from Mongo to JSON schema compliant JSON -->
    <scripting:transformer doc:name="Map Mongo object to JSON">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
           def brandsPayload = flowVars.brandResponses
            def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
            def root = builder {
                orgId payload._id.toString()
                //...
                isActive payload.platformHeader.isActive
                brands(brandsPayload.collect {it})
            }
            return builder.toPrettyString();
        ]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:transformer>
```

Resulting JSON

```
{
    "orgId": "5565f305b85c31182a65a6a7",
    "isActive": true,
    "brands": [
        "{
        "brandId": "5565f2ff03758e0c189a753d",
        "isActive": true
        }",
        "{
        "brandId": "5565f2ff03758e0c189a7594",
        "isActive": true
        }"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact you store string representation of the brands in `brandResponses`, thus you collect them as strings in the final JSON.

Note that for producing JSON, there's no big gain in using Groovy. Building Maps/Lists with MEL and serializing them to JSON Objects/Arrays with the `json:object-to-json-transformer` is way easier (as a comparison, Grooxy would be easier for XML generation).

In any case, to fix your issue:

- remove the first `scripting:transformer`
- replace the expression component to store brands in maps instead of strings, with: `brandResponses.add(["brandId":payload._id.toString(), "isActive":payload.platformHeader.isActive])`

I believe that should do it. If not, you may need to review the `collect` closure to generate JSON properly.

Comment: Thanks David, your answer was really helpful while constructing solution for similar problem with latest Mongo DB Connector v4.2.0 (answered below)

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of [MongoDb connector (v4.2.0)](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mongodb-connector) is very different than previous versions. [Input and Output formats are different](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mongo-apidoc) for each operation.

I was facing similar problem while converting Document object to JSON `json:object-to-json-transformer`

Solution is similar : put `expression-component` with below code before converting org.bson.Document object to JSON

```
payload.append("id",payload.getObjectId("_id").toString())
```

[Document.append()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/) method return back the updated document object.

[image]

Hope this help.